# How to delete a value from the CSV json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a JSON response as :

```
xxx: ["fsd,das"]
```

So I need to delete the value "fsd" from the json object but the problem is the response inside json is not the array , it is csv , so how do I delete it.
If anyone can come with the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `flat`ten, `split` and `join` the array with a comma, and `splice` out the value you don't want using `indexOf()`:

```js
var obj = {xxx: ["a,b","c,d","e","f,g,h","i,j,k"]}

var letter = prompt()
obj.xxx = obj.xxx.flat().join(',').split(',')

var index = obj.xxx.indexOf(letter)
obj.xxx.splice(index, 1)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: What if the structure is {xxx: ["fsd,das","aaa","bbb"]} or may contain more values and I need to delete the value based on dynamic parameter , i.e if I get "fsd" then is should be deleted if I get "aaa" then it should be deleted and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I can see, inside the json object it is an array of string.
Take that string use `str.replace()` to delete that part from it and put it back.